# Save PDF File From Plugin to Filesystem /wp_upload

Tags: filesystem, customization

i would like to call a function from another plugin, that returns a pdf. Is there a possibility to save this pdf in the Wordpress Filesystem - wp-upload for example?

I just found $wp_filesystem->put_contents but it seems to be designed for writing text-files.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot,
Steven

Comment: See the example [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_sideload/#comment-983) or [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_handle_sideload/#comment-1321), except you'd set `$tmp`/`$temp_file` to the file path without calling `download_url()`. The first example creates an attachment, in addition to "uploading" the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sally :)